# NixOS: How to granularly configure locale settings?

Tags: locale, nixos

On my home laptop running NixOS 19.03, in `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`, I use the default locale settings:

```
  i18n = {
    consoleFont = "Lat2-Terminus16";
    consoleKeyMap = "us";
    defaultLocale = "en_US.UTF-8";
  };
```

That's the only way I know to control locale settings in NixOS, and it's too broad. I want more granular control, so that I can use a mixture of US English and Colombian Spanish. (That's a consequence of my job, not a personal choice.) Specifically, I need these settings:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=es_CO.UTF-8
LC_TIME=es_CO.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=es_CO.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=es_CO.UTF-8
LC_NAME=es_CO.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=es_CO.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=es_CO.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=es_CO.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=es_CO.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

On my work desktop (running Ubuntu 18.04), if I evaluate `locale` in bash, that's what I see. On my home NixOS system, each of those variables is either set to US English or nothing:

```
[jeff@jbb-dell:~/nix-jbb]$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

I thought maybe I should edit `/etc/locale.conf`, copying the settings from my work system into it. But when (on the NixOS system) I print that file to screen, it doesn't include any of the above variables except `LANG`:

```
[jeff@jbb-dell:~/nix-jbb]$ cat /etc/locale.conf
LANG=en_US.UTF-8

[jeff@jbb-dell:~/nix-jbb]$
```

Therefore the other variables, like `LC_NUMERIC`, must be getting set somewhere else. I'm worried that if I edit `/etc/locale.conf` I'll break my system. Is editing that file the right way to set granular locale information in NixOS? And if not, what is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option [`i18n.extralocalesettings`](https://nixos.org/nixos/options.html#i18n.extralocalesettings) is where to set those. E.g.:

```hs
i18n.extraLocaleSettings = {
  LC_MESSAGES = "en_US.UTF-8";
  LC_TIME = "de_DE.UTF-8";
}
```

Comment: It looks like that works -- that's the solution I seem to have adopted after asking the folks at the NixOS Discourse forum, way back when.

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen a NixOS setting for that, but I guess you can work around that with:

```
  services.xserver.displayManager = {
    sessionCommands = ''
      export LC_NUMERIC=es_CO.UTF-8
      export LC_TIME=es_CO.UTF-8
      export LC_MONETARY=es_CO.UTF-8
      export LC_PAPER=es_CO.UTF-8
      export LC_NAME=es_CO.UTF-8
      export LC_ADDRESS=es_CO.UTF-8
      export LC_TELEPHONE=es_CO.UTF-8
      export LC_MEASUREMENT=es_CO.UTF-8
      export LC_IDENTIFICATION=es_CO.UTF-8
    '';
  };
```

This should work for all your local (graphical) sessions. If you access this computer with ssh as well, you might add the same exports also to `~/.bashrc`

If you don't want to have the setting for all users, you can also add the exports to `~/.xession` instead of `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` as shown above.